# Artemis + Queue Added under Adress while executing queue stat command

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have executed following command in Artemis 2.11.0 to get queue message count.

```
./artemis queue stat --user admin --password admin --queueName Test-InputQueue --url tcp://localhost:61616
```

After executing above command the `activemq.management` address is created under address. Please find attached screenshot for more details.[image] Can anyone let me know how I can remove above address without clean restart?

Please find below broker.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <thread-pool-max-size>200</thread-pool-max-size>
        <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
        <paging-directory>${data.dir}/paging</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>${data.dir}/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>${data.dir}/journal</journal-directory>
        <node-manager-lock-directory>${lock.dir}/artemis1-lock</node-manager-lock-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>${data.dir}/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
        <journal-min-files>50</journal-min-files>
        <journal-pool-files>100</journal-pool-files>
        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
        <page-max-concurrent-io>10</page-max-concurrent-io>
        <journal-compact-min-files>150</journal-compact-min-files>
        <journal-buffer-timeout>23480000</journal-buffer-timeout>
        <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
        <server-dump-interval>60000</server-dump-interval>
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>LOG</critical-analyzer-policy>

        <transaction-timeout>1800000</transaction-timeout>
        <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <ha-policy>
            <shared-store>
                <master>
                    <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                </master>
            </shared-store>
        </ha-policy>
        
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection-uri address="static://(tcp://localhost:61617)?connectorName=netty-connector;retryInterval=500;useDuplicateDetection=true;messageLoadBalancingType=ON_DEMAND;maxHops=1" name="my-cluster"/>
        </cluster-connections>

        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues-delay>5000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
                <auto-delete-addresses-delay>5000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <redistribution-delay>10000</redistribution-delay>
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues-delay>5000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
                <auto-delete-addresses-delay>5000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
            </address-setting>          
        </address-settings>
        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>          
        </addresses>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: we are using artemis 2.11.0

Comment: I have added broker.xml in above comment